# Partial Differential limits question.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a PDE that I solve to be: $$u(x,t) = f(x+at) + g(x-at)$$

I need to apply initial conditions, $u(x,0)=r(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=s(x)$

From this I get:

$$f(x)+g(x)=r(x)$$

and

$$a(f'(x)-g'(x) = s(x)$$
$$f(x) - g(x) = \frac {1}{a} \int s(x)dx + c$$

Could I ask, what would the limits of the integral of $s(x)$ be and why? From there I know how to complete the question. Thanks!

Comment: The upper limit has to be $x$. The lower limit, choose any constant you like - they'll cancel in the final solution anyway.

Comment: Why would it have to be x?

Comment: Because you're finding the anti-derivative. Think of it this way - the integral has to be the same on both sides. So $$\int_b^x f'(x) - g'(x)dx = \frac1a\int_b^x s(x)dx$$ The left side evaluates to $f(x)-g(x)-f(b)+g(b)$, and the values at $b$, as I said, will cancel in the final solution.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose.

1) Consider definite integral
$$
f(x)-g(x)=\frac 1a\int_{x_0}^xs(t)dt
$$
so, no constant, or

2) Indefinite integral(no limits)
$$
f(x)-g(x)=\frac 1a \int s(x)dx
$$
where after taking antiderivative you'll need to add constant of integration, i.e. that indefinite integral notation already includes constant. Anyway, in conjunction with first condition, it should give you unique solution.